# Using Magento Like Ebay

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to use magento's multi store system like ebay.

I want to use stores on one domain and using the same root category but every store can have different price on every single product and I want every store to be multilingual.

Before I start I appreciate some direction, which way would be best practise to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot (reasonably) be done in Magento, mainly because pricing cannot be set at the store level AND each scope (website/store) comes with a not-insignificant performance hit. MANY have tried what you are proposing. None have succeeded. Sorry.

Comment: Reindexing is going to kill you.

Comment: what is the alternative ? multiple vendors can sell on the same platform and ebay takes a cut out of it. Is there a powerful store like system for multivendor something similar ebay ? which also includes possibility of payment gateway integration ?

Comment: Not an endorsement, but please see https://secure.unirgy.com/products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there has many Magento extension can extend one Magento site into one Marketplace, which can let customer apply to be as one seller to sell their products as vendor on this common market.

Like:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/medma-marketplace.html
...